# When a subspace of a space is totally disconnected

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness, geometric-topology

Let $X $ be a  topological space and $Y $ a Hausdorff  subspace of $X $ such that for every connected component $C $ of $X $ the set $C\cap Y $ is finite. How can we show that $Y $ is totally disconnected?

My proof: Let $A $ be a connected component of $Y $. Then there is a connected component $C $ of $X $ such that $A\subseteq C $. This show that $A $ is finite and since $Y $ is Hausdorff, $A $  must be a single point. Hence $Y $ is totally disconnected. IS THIS PROOF TRUE ?

Comment: My edit was for a typo ("PROOP").

Comment: Looks ok to me..

Comment: @DanielWainfleet:Do you mean the proof is true?

Comment: Yes. The proof is true.